# CSS navbar keeps shifting around when resizing browser window

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS navbar, but whenever I try resizing the browser window the navbar creates a new row instead of continuing offscreen. I already tried adding a `min-width`, which worked for the other divs on my site, but it's not doing anything

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oddrmg9w/
The white space on the left is intented, that's where the logo is going to be.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is that You have a `fixed` positioned element within an `absolute`-ly positioned element.

In the most common case, Your main navigation will be set to a position of `fixed` in order for it to be taken out of the document flow, sticking it to a permanent position on the screen, which stays above all the content.

In this case, the problem is that you have to remove the `.navbar ul`'s position of `fixed` and apply it to your `.navbar` container as so:

```
.navbar {
  min-width: 720px;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ff2d2d;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0px;
  left: 240px;
  right: 0px;
}

.navbar li {
  float: left;
}

.navbar li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar li a:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Where the `left` and `right` values tell the element to stick to the left and right walls of your browser window, no matter what. You can also add a `top: 0` property which will stick your container to the top of the window.

Here is a **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oddrmg9w/1/)** with what I think that You want to achieve.

You should brush up on Your html and css fundamentals. So I suggest that you read further about positioning in the [**Mozilla Developer Network's site.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: You got it Paulie, just a second.

Comment: Alright, thanks. That's so simple but I just didn't think about it. I'm still learning so I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the div to keeps its width and let it exit the visible screen, just move the `position: fixed` and all its settings from the `ul` to the `navbar` 
:

```
.navbar {
    min-width: 720px;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0px;
    left: 240px;
    right: 0px;
}

.navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ff2d2d;
}
```

```css
.navbar {
  min-width: 720px;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0px;
  left: 240px;
  right: 0px;
}
.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ff2d2d;
}
.navbar li {
  float: left;
}
.navbar li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar li a:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li style="float: right;"> <a href="About.html">About </a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="Dtier.php">D-tier</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="Ctier.php">C-tier</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="Btier.php">B-tier</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="Atier.php">A-tier</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a class="active" href="Stier.php">S-tier</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="vote.php">Vote</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: ah, that's so simple but I just didn't think of it. Thanks!